# Watchdog Kernel Module Unknown symbol watchdog_register_device

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module, beagleboneblack

currently I am trying to develop a Kernel Module to control the hardware Watchdog and when it is not fed turn off the system, as watchdog should. I know there is a user space daemon already in place that can be "controlled" from the /dev/watchdog file but I need a kernel module. To expand on that I already have a kernel module to receive GPIO input, have registered an IRQ for that, and would like that IRQ to feed the watchdog. Thus if the GPIO interrupt doesn't fire in X amount of time the system shuts down.

However, I am having trouble getting the watchdog header file to cooperate with me. I read the little documentation there is on watchdog kernel api from here https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/watchdog/watchdog-kernel-api.txt but this seems to say it will just work.

Below I have pasted my test code for getting a watchdog to register followed by the error I am running into.

testWatchdog.c

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/file.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/fcntl.h>
#include <linux/watchdog.h>

static int __init watchdog_init(void)
{
    struct watchdog_device test;
    printk(KERN_INFO "WATCHDOG\n");
    watchdog_register_device(&test);
    test.ops->start(&test);
    test.ops->ping(&test);
    return 0;
}

static void __exit watchdog_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "GG!!!\n");
}

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

module_init(watchdog_init);
module_exit(watchdog_exit);
```

Makefile

```
obj-m += testWatchdog.o

export EXTRA_CFLAGS := -std=gnu99

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

The code I do have can be made but when running insmod I get an error

> insmod: error inserting './testWatchdog.ko': -1 Invalid parameters

After running dmesg I see the following error

> Unknown symbol watchdog_register_device (err 0)

If anyone could please at least point me in the correct direction I would appreciate it a lot. I'm fairly new to kernel modules but am hopeful for this.

UPDATE:
For some reason I decided to rerun this insmod command and my output has changed. As far as I know I didn't change anything but maybe I updated a file. Anyway when I try to insmod now I don't get an error but my Kernel says I'm doing a null pointer dereference. Here is the output of my error.

```
[68964.787385] WATCHDOG
[68964.787405] BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 00000005
[68964.787409] IP: [<f84c7020>] watchdog_init+0x20/0x1000 [testWatchdog]
[68964.787420] *pdpt = 000000003676a001 *pde = 0000000000000000 
[68964.787423] Oops: 0000 [#1] SMP 
[68964.787427] Modules linked in: testWatchdog(OF+) vboxsf(OF) vesafb(F) microcode(F) vboxguest(OF) psmouse(F) serio_raw(F) i2c_piix4(F) mac_hid(F) vboxvideo(OF) rfcomm(F) bnep(F) parport_pc(F) bluetooth(F) ppdev(F) drm(F) binfmt_misc(F) lp(F) parport(F) pcnet32(F) ahci(F) libahci(F)
[68964.787446] Pid: 3180, comm: insmod Tainted: GF          O 3.8.0-34-generic #49~precise1-Ubuntu innotek GmbH VirtualBox/VirtualBox
[68964.787448] EIP: 0060:[<f84c7020>] EFLAGS: 00010296 CPU: 0
[68964.787451] EIP is at watchdog_init+0x20/0x1000 [testWatchdog]
[68964.787453] EAX: e1989e3c EBX: f84c4000 ECX: 00000000 EDX: 00000001
[68964.787455] ESI: 00001299 EDI: e1989f60 EBP: e1989eb8 ESP: e1989e38
[68964.787456]  DS: 007b ES: 007b FS: 00d8 GS: 00e0 SS: 0068
[68964.787461] CR0: 8005003b CR2: 00000005 CR3: 34865000 CR4: 000006f0
[68964.787477] DR0: 00000000 DR1: 00000000 DR2: 00000000 DR3: 00000000
[68964.787482] DR6: ffff0ff0 DR7: 00000400
[68964.787484] Process insmod (pid: 3180, ti=e1988000 task=f3f5e680 task.ti=e1988000)
[68964.787485] Stack:
[68964.787487]  f84c3024 c103fb63 00000000 e1989ed0 00000000 00000000 e1989eac c1040885
[68964.787492]  00000000 e1989e6c 00000000 f84c8000 00000001 00000000 80000000 e1989ed0
[68964.787496]  00000000 80000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 00000001 0003d5dc c10decd6
[68964.787501] Call Trace:
[68964.787528]  [<c103fb63>] ? cpa_flush_range+0x43/0xc0
[68964.787532]  [<c1040885>] ? change_page_attr_set_clr+0x225/0x250
[68964.787543]  [<c10decd6>] ? tracepoint_module_notify+0x26/0xc0
[68964.787546]  [<f84c7000>] ? 0xf84c6fff
[68964.787549]  [<c1040a7f>] ? set_memory_nx+0x5f/0x70
[68964.787552]  [<c1003054>] do_one_initcall+0x34/0x170
[68964.787555]  [<f84c7000>] ? 0xf84c6fff
[68964.787567]  [<c161b039>] do_init_module+0x80/0x1c6
[68964.787583]  [<c10af03b>] load_module+0x41b/0x5f0
[68964.787586]  [<c10acee0>] ? add_kallsyms+0x1e0/0x1e0
[68964.787611]  [<c12f92f2>] ? _copy_from_user+0x42/0x60
[68964.787615]  [<c10af296>] sys_init_module+0x86/0xa0
[68964.787620]  [<c163518d>] sysenter_do_call+0x12/0x28
[68964.787622] Code: <ff> 52 04 8b 55 d0 8d 45 84 ff 52 0c 31 c0 c9 c3 00 00 00 00 00 00
[68964.787642] EIP: [<f84c7020>] watchdog_init+0x20/0x1000 [testWatchdog] SS:ESP 0068:e1989e38
[68964.787646] CR2: 0000000000000005
[68964.787650] ---[ end trace fd9234fd8f14c123 ]---
```

Comment: In your .config file CONFIG_WATCHDOG_CORE=y ???

Comment: In my /usr/src/(uname -r)-generic/.config file CONFIG_WATCHDOG_CORE=y

Comment: Just look at this driver http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/misc/mei/wd.c?a=arm#L367. Panic is because `test` is passed without initialized with proper data.

Comment: Thank you I just started realizing how silly I've been. I for some reason though that watchdog_register_device was like the initialization for an empty struct. Makes more sense now.